# CTAN package 'invoice' on texlive debian/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, tex-core

I am trying to use the 'invoice' latex package, which is supposed to be in texlive-latex-extra, however I keep getting the error "invoice.sty not found" at my `\usepackage{invoice}` line.

I installed texlive-latex-extra and texlive-generic-extra which didn't do the trick, and then I installed texlive-full, but I'm still getting the same error.

Has this package been removed from texlive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you tagged your question with ubuntu/debian, so what version of texlive are you using?  The texlive that ships with ubuntu is fairly old, so perhaps `invoice` hasn't been added to it yet...  At least, on a hand-made texlive install, I get

```
tlmgr show --list invoice
(omitted lines)
Included files, by type:
run files:
  RELOC/tex/latex/invoice/invoice.def
  RELOC/tex/latex/invoice/invoice.sty
```

Comment: I'm using the version that ships with Ubuntu 11.10. This seems to be version: 2009-13...